# If $f : [a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is monotonic on $[a,b]$, then $\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ exists and it is equal to $\sup\{f(x)\,:\,x\in[a,b)\}$

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is monotonic on $[a,b]$, then the left limit $\lim_{x\to b^-} f(x)$ exists and it is equal to $\sup\{f(x)\,:\,x\in[a,b)\}$

I know that the limit exists but I need someone to confirm whether it is equal to $\sup\{f(x)\,:\,x\in[a,b)\}$

Thank you

Comment: I confirm that it is true.

Comment: I never said anything about continuity I asked about the limit at the endpoint

Comment: Nevermind, I misread, I thought the supremum was taken in $[a,b]$.

Comment: oh ok thanks to both of you guys

Comment: I just don't understand the downvotes they make no sense to me

Comment: Well, actually you need monotonic **increasing**. There are also monotonic **decreasing** functions.

Comment: aye aye that's right thanks

Comment: @OmarQasem Don't worry too much about the downvotes.  They are meaningless in real life.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ given and $M=\sup E$ with $E=\{f(x),x\in [a,b)\}$.

then

$\exists y_0\in E \;:\; M-\epsilon <y_0\leq M$

$\exists x_0\in [a,b)\;:\: M-\epsilon<f(x_0)\leq M$

$$\implies \forall x\in (x_0,b) \;\; $$

$$M-\epsilon<f(x_0)\leq f(x)\leq M$$

put $x_0=b-\eta$

then

$$\forall x\in(b-\eta,b)\;\; |f(x)-M|<\epsilon$$

$$\lim_{x\to b^-}=M$$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L = \sup\{f(x) : x∈[a,b)\}$.

For arbitrary $\epsilon \in (0, \frac{|b-a|}{2})$ consider $(L - \epsilon, L)$. By assumption, the preimage of $(L - \epsilon, L)$ must be nonempty, otherwise, since $f$ clearly cannot attain its supremum $L$, $L-\epsilon$ would be the $\sup$ instead. Thus, for some $d \in [a,b)$, $f(d) \in (L - \epsilon, L)$.

We need to show for some $\delta>0$ $f[(b - \delta, b)] \subset (L - \epsilon, L)$. This is equivalent to the assertion that

$$\lim_{x \to b^{-}} f(x) = L$$

We can prove this by contradiction.

Suppose to the contrary that for all $\delta >0$ there is some $c_{\delta} \in (b - \delta, b)$ with $f(c_{\delta}) \notin (L - \epsilon, L)$. Then we must have $f(c_{\delta}) \leq L - \epsilon$. Note that such a $c_{\delta}$ exists regardless of our choice of $\delta$.

Thus, if we choose $\delta_0$ such that $a< d < b - \delta_0 < c_{\delta_0} < b$ we have $f(d) \leq f(c_{\delta_0}) \leq L - \epsilon$ since $f$ is increasing. This contradicts the fact that $f(d) \in (L - \epsilon, L)$.